# SHA256を計算したものの、答えが合わない

Tags: cuda

https://github.com/Horkyze/CudaSHA256
を参考に、CUDAを使って `char*` からsha256を計算しようとしています。が、計算されたsha256が正しくありません。桁は正しいのですが...コードは上のリポジトリのコードを少し変更(元のコードは、ファイルからsha256を生成するものだったので、文字列からsha256を生成するように)し、下のようにしました。

**期待値:**

```
a → ca978112ca1bbdcafac231b39a23dc4da786eff8147c4e72b9807785afee48bb
```

**出力された値:**

```
a → 505736ebd7b9555264ec0a456d050eb53acaac883bd2e9098425e182290ec36f
```

どうかどなたか、どこが修正部分か教えいただけるとありがたいです。

##### 追記:

回答をもとに、`sha256_update(&ctx, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(trim((char*)"a")), 1);` と出力されたハッシュ値を変更しました。

```
#define SHA256_BLOCK_SIZE 32 // SHA256 outputs a 32 byte digest

#define ROTLEFT(a, b) (((a) << (b)) | ((a) >> (32 - (b))))
#define ROTRIGHT(a, b) (((a) >> (b)) | ((a) << (32 - (b))))
#define CH(x, y, z) (((x) & (y)) ^ (~(x) & (z)))
#define MAJ(x, y, z) (((x) & (y)) ^ ((x) & (z)) ^ ((y) & (z)))
#define EP0(x) (ROTRIGHT(x, 2) ^ ROTRIGHT(x, 13) ^ ROTRIGHT(x, 22))
#define EP1(x) (ROTRIGHT(x, 6) ^ ROTRIGHT(x, 11) ^ ROTRIGHT(x, 25))
#define SIG0(x) (ROTRIGHT(x, 7) ^ ROTRIGHT(x, 18) ^ ((x) >> 3))
#define SIG1(x) (ROTRIGHT(x, 17) ^ ROTRIGHT(x, 19) ^ ((x) >> 10))
#define BCD(c) 5 * (5 * (5 * (5 * (5 * (5 * (5 * (5*(5*(c&512)+(c&256))+(c&128))+(c&64))+(c&32))+(c&16))+(c&8))+(c&4))+(c&2))+(c&1)
/**************************** DATA TYPES ****************************/
typedef unsigned char BYTE; // 8-bit byte
typedef uint32_t WORD;      // 32-bit word, change to "long" for 16-bit machines

typedef struct JOB
{
    BYTE* data;
    unsigned long long size;
    BYTE digest[64];
} JOB;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE data[64];
    WORD datalen;
    unsigned long long bitlen;
    WORD state[8];
} SHA256_CTX;

__constant__ WORD dev_k[64];

static const WORD host_k[64] = {
    0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
    0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
    0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
    0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
    0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
    0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
    0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
    0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2 };

/*********************** FUNCTION DECLARATIONS **********************/
char* print_sha(BYTE* buff);
__device__ void sha256_init(SHA256_CTX* ctx);
__device__ void sha256_update(SHA256_CTX* ctx, const BYTE data[], size_t len);
__device__ void sha256_final(SHA256_CTX* ctx, BYTE hash[]);
__device__ int isspace(unsigned char c) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\f' || c == '\v';
}
__device__ char* trim(char* str) {
    size_t len = 0;
    char* frontp = str;
    char* endp = NULL;

    if (str == NULL) { return NULL; }
    if (str[0] == '\0') { return str; }
    for(int len=0; str[len] != '\0'; len++) {
        if(str[len] != ' ') {
            endp = str + len;
            break;
        }
    }
    endp = str + len;

    /* Move the front and back pointers to address the first non-whitespace
     * characters from each end.
     */
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*frontp)) { ++frontp; }
    if (endp != frontp)
    {
        while (isspace((unsigned char)*(--endp)) && endp != frontp) {}
    }

    if (str + len - 1 != endp)
        *(endp + 1) = '\0';
    else if (frontp != str && endp == frontp)
        *str = '\0';

    /* Shift the string so that it starts at str so that if it's dynamically
     * allocated, we can still free it on the returned pointer.  Note the reuse
     * of endp to mean the front of the string buffer now.
     */
    endp = str;
    if (frontp != str)
    {
        while (*frontp) { *endp++ = *frontp++; }
        *endp = '\0';
    }


    return str;
}
char* hash_to_string(BYTE* buff)
{
    char* string = (char*)malloc(70);
    int k, i;
    for (i = 0, k = 0; i < 32; i++, k += 2)
    {
        sprintf(string + k, "%.2x", buff[i]);
        // printf("%02x", buff[i]);
    }
    string[64] = 0;
    return string;
}

__device__ void sha256_transform(SHA256_CTX* ctx, const BYTE data[])
{
    
    WORD a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, t1, t2, m[64];
    WORD S[8];

    //mycpy32(S, ctx->state);

#pragma unroll 16
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 16; ++i, j += 4)
        m[i] = (data[j] << 24) | (data[j + 1] << 16) | (data[j + 2] << 8) | (data[j + 3]);

#pragma unroll 64
    for (; i < 64; ++i)
        m[i] = SIG1(m[i - 2]) + m[i - 7] + SIG0(m[i - 15]) + m[i - 16];

    a = ctx->state[0];
    b = ctx->state[1];
    c = ctx->state[2];
    d = ctx->state[3];
    e = ctx->state[4];
    f = ctx->state[5];
    g = ctx->state[6];
    h = ctx->state[7];

#pragma unroll 64
    for (i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
        t1 = h + EP1(e) + CH(e, f, g) + dev_k[i] + m[i];
        t2 = EP0(a) + MAJ(a, b, c);
        h = g;
        g = f;
        f = e;
        e = d + t1;
        d = c;
        c = b;
        b = a;
        a = t1 + t2;
    }

    ctx->state[0] += a;
    ctx->state[1] += b;
    ctx->state[2] += c;
    ctx->state[3] += d;
    ctx->state[4] += e;
    ctx->state[5] += f;
    ctx->state[6] += g;
    ctx->state[7] += h;
    
}

__device__ void sha256_init(SHA256_CTX* ctx)
{
    ctx->datalen = 0;
    ctx->bitlen = 0;
    ctx->state[0] = 0x6a09e667;
    ctx->state[1] = 0xbb67ae85;
    ctx->state[2] = 0x3c6ef372;
    ctx->state[3] = 0xa54ff53a;
    ctx->state[4] = 0x510e527f;
    ctx->state[5] = 0x9b05688c;
    ctx->state[6] = 0x1f83d9ab;
    ctx->state[7] = 0x5be0cd19;
}

__device__ void sha256_update(SHA256_CTX* ctx, const BYTE data[], size_t len)
{
    WORD i;

    // for each byte in message
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        // ctx->data == message 512 bit chunk
        ctx->data[ctx->datalen] = data[i];
        ctx->datalen++;
        if (ctx->datalen == 64) {
            sha256_transform(ctx, ctx->data);
            ctx->bitlen += 512;
            ctx->datalen = 0;
        }
    }
}

__device__ void sha256_final(SHA256_CTX* ctx, BYTE hash[])
{
    WORD i;

    i = ctx->datalen;

    // Pad whatever data is left in the buffer.
    if (ctx->datalen < 56) {
        ctx->data[i++] = 0x80;
        while (i < 56)
            ctx->data[i++] = 0x00;
    }
    else {
        ctx->data[i++] = 0x80;
        while (i < 64)
            ctx->data[i++] = 0x00;
        sha256_transform(ctx, ctx->data);
        memset(ctx->data, 0, 56);
    }

    // Append to the padding the total message's length in bits and transform.
    ctx->bitlen += ctx->datalen * 8;
    ctx->data[63] = ctx->bitlen;
    ctx->data[62] = ctx->bitlen >> 8;
    ctx->data[61] = ctx->bitlen >> 16;
    ctx->data[60] = ctx->bitlen >> 24;
    ctx->data[59] = ctx->bitlen >> 32;
    ctx->data[58] = ctx->bitlen >> 40;
    ctx->data[57] = ctx->bitlen >> 48;
    ctx->data[56] = ctx->bitlen >> 56;
    sha256_transform(ctx, ctx->data);

    // Since this implementation uses little endian byte ordering and SHA uses big endian,
    // reverse all the bytes when copying the final state to the output hash.
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        hash[i] = (ctx->state[0] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        hash[i + 4] = (ctx->state[1] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        hash[i + 8] = (ctx->state[2] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        hash[i + 12] = (ctx->state[3] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        hash[i + 16] = (ctx->state[4] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        hash[i + 20] = (ctx->state[5] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        hash[i + 24] = (ctx->state[6] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        hash[i + 28] = (ctx->state[7] >> (24 - i * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
    }

}

#define checkCudaErrors(x)                                                    \
    {                                                                         \
        cudaGetLastError();                                                   \
        x;                                                                    \
        cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();                                 \
        if (err != cudaSuccess)                                               \
            printf("GPU: cudaError %d (%s)\n", err, cudaGetErrorString(err)); \
    }
__global__ void sha256_cuda(BYTE* result)
{
int trlen = 0;
    for (; mae[strlen] != '\0'; strlen++);

    SHA256_CTX ctx;
    sha256_init(&ctx);//　　　　aの値を計算したい
    sha256_update(&ctx, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(trim((char*)"a")), 1);
    BYTE digest[64];
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++)
    {
        digest[a] = 0xff;
    }
    sha256_final(&ctx, (digest));
    for (int a = 0; a < 64; a++) {
        result[a] = digest[a];
    }

}
```

Comment: 元のコードからの変更点のポイントを書いておいた方がより親切かもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

CUDAコードが正しいかは確認していませんが、長さが間違っています。

> ```
> sha256_update(&ctx, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(trim((char*)"a")), 8);
> ```

この指定では、`a`の後ろを余分に７バイト参照しています。`a`１バイト分の計算をするのであれば、`8`ではなく`1`でなければなりません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうでした。すみません。
しかし修正後もいまだ誤った値が出力されます。505736ebd7b9555264ec0a456d050eb53acaac883bd2e9098425e182290ec36f